# Adding selective elements of one dictionary to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list as:

```
my_list = ["10", "12", "32", "23"]
```

and a dictionary as:

```
my_dict = {
    'one': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'AB', 'id': '10'},
    'two': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'CD', 'id': '12'}, 
    'three': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'EF', 'id': '32'}
    }
```

I want to keep a dictionary say final_dict which will have content of my_dict only if the id is present in my_list. I tried to do that by:

```
sf_dict = dict()

for list_id in my_list:
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if list_id == value['id']:
            print("Values : {} {} {}".format(value['index'], value['sec_key'], value['id']))
            sf_dict[key] = key
            sf_dict[key]['index'] = value['index']  
            sf_dict[key]['sec_key'] = value['sec_key']
            sf_dict[key]['id'] = value['id']
        
print(sf_dict)
```

I'm able to print the values but the assigning of those values is failing due to the error as:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: you should be writing sf_dict[key] = value not sf_dict[key] = key, rest is not required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to loop over your `my_dict` and check if the value stored in `id` is in your list.

```
my_list = ["10", "12", "32", "23"]
my_dict = {
    'one': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'AB', 'id': '10'},
    'two': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'CD', 'id': '12'}, 
    'three': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'EF', 'id': '32'}
    }

result = {key:value for key, value in my_dict.items() if value['id'] in my_list}

#{'one': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'AB', 'id': '10'}, 'two': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'CD', 'id': '12'}, 'three': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'EF', 'id': '32'}}

my_list = ["10"]

#{'one': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'AB', 'id': '10'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The already given answers should do the trick, altough maybe it is important to get why your approach isn't right.

The problem with what you did is that when you do `sf_dict[key] = key`, you're setting the value of the dictionary for the key `key` with the value `key`. But `key` is a string, thus, when you later try `sf_dict[key]['index'] = value['index']` it tells you that you cannot assign on top a string.

Try to remove these lines

```
sf_dict[key]['index'] = value['index']  
sf_dict[key]['sec_key'] = value['sec_key']
sf_dict[key]['id'] = value['id']
```

and simply replace them with `sf_dict[key] = value`. This way, when you find the id you're searching for, you assign all the dictionary at once to the corresponding key.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
final_dict={}
for i in my_dict:
    if my_dict[i]['id'] in my_list:
        final_dict[i]=my_dict[i]
```

Example:

```
my_list = ["10", "32", "23"]
```

Output:

```
print(final_dict)
{'one': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'AB', 'id': '10'}, 'three': {'index': 0, 'sec_key': 'EF', 'id': '32'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for list_id in my_list:
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if list_id == value['id']:
            print("Values : {} {} {}".format(value['index'], value['sec_key'], value['id']))
            sf_dict[key] = {'index':value['index'],'sec_key':value['sec_key'],'id':value['id']}

print(sf_dict)
```

the code should be like this.

Comment: yeah my bad. I realize there are lots of tricks to do, dict comprehension...

Answer (score 1):

#problem is here

```
sf_dict[key] = key
```

above line means sf_dict = {'one': 'one'} for example

so next lines mean 'one'['anything'] = 
so using index to assign into str is not allowed.

better solution is already answered above, just pointing issue in exist code